stm32 nucleo board programming
i am using a stm32 nucleo board (NUCLEO-WL55JC2) . I was trying to store some data in the EEPROM , but i think i acessed some d,ault configuration, so it is showing some error while running and debugging the code in controller , such as
while debugging i am getting,
warning: ARM M in lockup state, stack unwinding terminated.
set *(unsigned int *)0xe00430a0&=~0x1
set *(int )0xE000EDFC=(int *)0xE000EDFC|0x7F0
set *(unsigned int *)0xe0043000&=~0x1
i am planning to change the bootloader code of the controller , the controller in the nucleo board is STM32F723IEK6 , i searched a lot , but i am not getting the bootloader code , if any one has the code please refer me the link to download, or if my idea is bad ,suggest a good idea

If you mean system bootloader, it's fixed in silicon and can't be changed. It's located at a specific memory address which you can find in the MCU reference manual.
